# Simple Android Debug tool

Tags: android, debugging

I'm not a developer, so i apologize if I don't phrase the question effectively.

I'm looking for a tool that will help show me what code is being executed as I step through the program. i am not looking to much more than take look under the hood as I test new features & uncover bugs for the new Android app my company is making.

Are there any specific emulators or tools that I could use for this simplistic purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has a built-in debugger. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for to make a debug inside Android Studio.

1-Debug using Logs
2-With logs lines and see on Logcat tool
3-With Breakpoints
and others.

This link its useful for you:
[Here](https://www.strv.com/blog/debugging-in-android-studio-as)